# “Invalid mode encountered: 9” when decoding with NSpeex

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, decoding, nspeex

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] Decode(byte[] encodedData)
{
    short[] decodedFrame = new short[160]; // should be the same number of samples as on the capturing side
    int decoderBytes = decoder.Decode(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length, decodedFrame, 0, false);
}
```

When I call this method:

```
byte[] decodedBuffer = this.Decode(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.ogg"));
```

I get “**Invalid mode encountered: 9**” error.

How to fix it? Did i do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try
https://sites.google.com/site/cobnut3d/

There are examples for C #